# Algorithm to generate non-linear histogram of time interval to future

Tags: algorithm, time-series, dynamically-generated, packet-capture

Does there exist any good algorithm to generate a non-linear histogram for time interval to future?

The problem is that I need to measure the packet delay in the buffer before it drained by a process. Assume start from some time point T(0), packets will be dropped into a buffer. And at some future time T(f), all the packets in the buffer will be claimed by a process at once. Thus, the delay for a packet should be the difference of the future time T(f) and its arrival time T(a): T(f)-T(a).

A non-liner histogram of such packet interval may have arbitrary distance, such as 0, 10, 25, 50, 100, 250, ..... (this can be defined better).

One way to get such histogram would be record each packet arrival time and then calculate the time interval at T(f). However, this will consume a great amount of memory.

I am wondering whether there is a dynamic algorithm can generate/update such histogram  during run-time (do the calculation at each packet arrival without consuming too much memory)?

Comment: Could you state the problem more clearly? I understand that your program receives two kinds of events: new packet and process'es claim for all the packets, but what is it that you want do show with the histogram? Number of packets in buffer in course of time?  Distribution of packets' age for current moment?

Comment: Sorry for the misleading. I want to show the distribution of packets's age in the buffer. The packet age is the time difference between the future process's claiming time T(f) and packet arrival time T(a). For example, in the histogram, I want to show there are 100 packets with age below 5ms, 300 packets with age between 5ms-25ms, etc.

Answer (score 0):

A histogram needs a map B(x) that takes a data value x to a bucket B where a count is maintained.  If the counts are stored (as is usual) in an array, then B(x) is the index of the count in the array.  When the buckets are of equal size, B(x) is particularly simple: B(x) = floor((x - A) / N) where A is the minimum possible value of x and N is the bucket size (this assumes the counts are in an array with 0-based indices).

If the buckets are not of equal size, the B(x) is more complicated.  You can always store the bucket boundaries in an array (call it b)

```
b[] = { 0, 10, 25, 50, 100, 250, ... }
```

This encodes the buckets [0..10), [10..25), etc. Now you can use binary search to compute

```
B(x) = index in b of greatest value not greater than or equal to x
```

If there is a precise logarithmic growth of buckets, such as [1, 10), [10, 100), [100, 1000), [1000, 10000), then you can use a logarithm-based map:

```
B(x) = floor( log_10(x) )
```

**Addition**

If the histogram must be accumulated on-line; that is, you don't know anything about the data until they arrive, then your algorithm must be able to reorganize B(x) on the fly.

If you allow B(x) to be any new map, then reorganization means reprocessing all data received so far so they can be re-assigned to the new buckets.  This requires O(N) time for N data received each time the histogram is reorganized. Many applications can't handle this expense.

If you allow *only adding new buckets*, then life gets considerably easier.  For example, with equal-sized buckets and B(x) = floor((x - A) / N) as discussed above, the problem is that you don't know A in advance.  The simplest technique is to set A equal to the first data value and maintain *two* arrays of buckets.  The first counts data with values greater than or equal to A using B(x) as given above.  The second counts data with values less than A using B'(x) = floor((A - x) / N). Obviously you guess at an initial size and then grow these arrays dynamically as needed to handle the absolute maximum values seen so far.

The same technique works fine for logarithmically sized buckets. Only you'll use something like B(x) = floor(log(x / A) / N) and B'(x) = floor(-log(x / A) / N).

One other kind of reorganization is easy: those restricted to adding *and/or merging* buckets.  This requires traversing the old bucket array and adding bucket counts to obtain new merged ones.  In the linear case, this equivalent to increasing N by an integer factor: 2*N is merging two buckets into one, etc.  The log case is similar.

This kind of reorganization works well if you choose a ridiculously small bucket size and let the buckets grow only enough to keep the histogram array sizes under some chosen threshold.  This doesn't cause much performance penalty.  Buckets must get at least 2 time bigger for each merge, so growth by a factor of F requires only log_2(F) mergings.  For example, if you expect the data to be around 1 and choose an initial linear bucket size of 1/1,000,000, it will still take only 20 twofold merges to make them of unit size.

To make this more concrete, here is pseudocode for the linear bucket case:

```
Let hi = [0]  ; Counts for data x >= A
Let lo = [0]  ; Counts for data x < A
Let N = < smallest imaginable desired bucket size >
Let N' = N
Let A = x[0]  ; Put first received data value in A
hi[0] = 1     ; Count the first data value

for each successive data value x
  if x >= A

    p = floor((x - A) / N)

    ; Grow if necessary. 
    while hi.last_index < p and a has not reached pre-determined max size
      grow hi by a factor of 2 and set new elements zero

    ; Merge if necessary
    while hi.last_index < p
      ; Merge 2 buckets into 1
      j = 0
      for i = 0 .. lo.last_index / 2
        hi[i] = hi[j] + hi[j + 1]
        j = j + 2
      ; Buckets are now half as big
      N = 2 * N
      p = floor((x - A) / N)
      ; Second half of hi is now available for higher values
      set second half of hi zero

    ; Count the data value
    increment hi[p]

  else
    p = floor((A - x) / N')

    ; Grow if necessary. 
    while lo.last_index < p and a has not reached pre-determined max size
      grow lo by a factor of 2 and set new elements zero

    ; Merge if necessary
    while lo.last_index < p
      ; Merge 2 buckets into 1
      j = 0
      for i = 0 .. lo.last_index / 2
        lo[i] = lo[j] + lo[j + 1]
        j = j + 2
      ; Buckets are now half as big
      N' = 2 * N'
      p = floor((A - x) / N')
      ; Second half of lo is now available for smaller values
      set second half of lo zero

    increment lo[p]
  end
```

This lets the buckets in the two arrays grow to different sizes.  If this is not what you want, just merge lo and hi together each time either is required to be.

I have used this algorithm with good success to instrument a general purpose factory simulator.

Comment: The algorithm will work if A is given such that B(x) can be calculated during run-time. However, for my problem, A is a future time which is unknown beforehand. Any suggestions?

Comment: I did not understand this from the way you worded your question. In this case you want an on-line histogram algorithm.  I outlined how to build one above. @user3209405